# wordpress, drupal, joomla... which is better for a BLOG with membership and videos?

Tags: wordpress, drupal, joomla, content-management-system, membership

I need a little help.  I want to built a user interactive site that allows members to upload videos, comments etc.

Which open source platform should I use that will allow greatest flexibility and growth?  I am a strong **PHP coder**, but haven't used many of the platforms out there.

Also any mods/or apps that might come in handy?

It would be nice if users could have their own page and user content was aggregated on the home page.  I would like to host my own videos instead of using youtube... have heard about zencoder for the videos... but still not sure what's the next best step.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: all good answers guys... makes the decision even tougher.  I think I will give a try to wordpress with the budypress add on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into Buddypress for Wordpress. Another one you can try is Drupal Commons. Both of these do a lot of the work for you so you can spend more time customizing instead of coding the functionality. My personal favorite is Wordpress for this kind of stuff

Comment: I checked out the buddypress for wordpress... pretty cool!! thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 2):

Wordpress is good for just Blogging. If you want some more data management then go for Drupal..

Answer (score 2):

wordpress is really good just for blogging. besides you can improve its performance by installing your required plugins for blogging like spam blocking, bad words filter etc. But data management is not so good for wordpress but not bad at all. At the beginning of my web development life, i hated this wordpress. but now i really love them. its cms is good and easy to maintain even for the noobs. cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of cms applications available such as joomla,wordpress,drupal,etc.. to create and manipulate dynamic websites.

You have to select a good one that satisfies your requirements.

I suggest you to select wordpress ,since it is very simple to integrate blogging sites..